# Rails Carrierwave Fog hide s3 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I want to let the user download file directly from S3, but does not want to expose the full directory. Currently I am able to achieve that with `AWS::S3` library by doing

```
S3Object.url_for('beluga_baby.jpg', 'marcel_molina')
```

and it will give me url like:

```
http://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename.png?AWSAccessKeyId=key&Expires=exp&Signature=signature
```

Is this achievable with fog alone? I tried to config fog like so:

```
config.fog_public = false
config.fog_authenticated_url_expiration = 600 # 10 minutes
```

But the directory of the file is still exposed, just with an expiration.

```
"https://bucketname.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/course_material/file/id/filename.png?AWSAccessKeyId=key&Signature=signature&Expires=exp"
```

Comment: The s3 URL will always contain the s3 bucket and key in full. Otherwise it wouldn't be able to find the file.

Comment: @doog what wrong in showing the bucket anyways since your url is protected by expiry time

Comment: @Viren I'm no worried about the bucket, but the directory like `uploads/course_material/file/id`

Comment: @doog worried in what sense since your `directory` is `not` public

Answer (score 0):

The url with the expiration is likely what you'll want (if you look closely at the result from S3Object you'll see it is that way also). Even if someone knows the name of the bucket and the path, they should not have access, unless you explicitly make the bucket public.